# phpmyadmin error during installation "Empty value for 'port' specified."

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I have been trying to install phpmyadmin on my digitalocean droplet using ubuntu 14.04 / mysql 5.7.12 .  I have a LAMP stack with apache as the web server.

During installation I keep getting the error shown here. [image: error message]
E

I am pretty new to phpmyadmin and wondering why I keep getting this.  Previously installing phpmyadmin with an older version of mysql was error free.  I am trying to install it as a non-root sudo user.

Any direction or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12246 if that applies to you as well

Comment: thanks, it seems to be the same problem but unfortunately no solution there either.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

My machine configuration
- Ubuntu 16.04
- MySql 5.7.13
- PHP 7.0.8
- Apache 2.4.18

Edit the file /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf, changing

`dbc_dbport=''` to `dbc_dbport='0'`

After editing the file and saving it, if you are still on the dbconfig-common wizard select **retry**; if not run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` (choose **Yes** when asked you if you want to Reinstall database for phpmyadmin) and continue normally without changing any value. If you want to change some value do it in the file that you have edited before.

When configuration window asks what you want to do with existing configuration file choose **Keep the local version currently installed**.

At this point you can check the differences and only those must exist that you made in the file.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Not only did I need to edit the port, I needed to edit my previously specified password in the same file to get things working. Up-vote done.

Answer (score 8):

I've searched the internet for hours but none worked for me except [this](http://www.servermom.org/install-phpmyadmin-ubuntu-16-04-lamp/).

After changing `dbc_dbport=''` to `dbc_dbport='0'` I still encountered some other problems.

If you are not able to continue the configuration process properly, follow these additional steps:

First, simply choose Abort.

Then login to mysql as root using the password you’ve defined when you installed MariaDB.

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Next, issue following command:

```
CREATE DATABASE phpmyadmin;
```

Then, issue following command:
(Do not forget to replace ***changethispassword*** with your own password of choice.)

```
GRANT ALL ON phpmyadmin.* TO phpmyadmin@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'changethispassword';
```

Exit *mysql>* using:

```
\q
```

Next, edit the database configuration:

```
sudo gedit /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php
```

Edit the dbpass parameter with the password you’ve just defined.

```
<?php
##
## database access settings in php format
## automatically generated from /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf
## by /usr/sbin/dbconfig-generate-include
##
## by default this file is managed via ucf, so you shouldn't have to
## worry about manual changes being silently discarded.  *however*,
## you'll probably also want to edit the configuration file mentioned
## above too.
##
$dbuser='phpmyadmin';
$dbpass='changethispassword';
$basepath='';
$dbname='phpmyadmin';
$dbserver='localhost';
$dbport='';
$dbtype='mysql';
```

Replace ***changethispassword*** with your own and save. (It must've been already set correctly.)

Answer (score 6):

MySQL behavior has changed here, so you have few options:

- Use older MySQL version prior this change
- Use Ubuntu packages which did revert this change (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dbconfig-common/+bug/1563274)
- Wait for fixing dbconfig-common, see https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=824537

Update: You can workaround this bug as described in [answer from William Ardila](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38924035/225718).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I set up manually for now. But comforting to know I wasn't the only one having that problem.

Comment: I'm getting the same error when I'm trying to install phpmyadmin, but I don't understand what are the steps for the solution. Can you explain a bit more detailed please ?

Comment: This does not help to solve the problem. @William Ardila's answer does.

Answer (score 5):

Our server config - Debian 8.x
Mysql 5.7
PHP 5+7
Apache 2.4

This should work :

- unistall phpmyadmin (--purge)
- reinstall phpmyadmin (ignore errors)
- check for existence of phpmyadmin user and/or database in mysql using mysql console or whatever means.
- If they don't exist, manually create them and GRANT phpmyadmin user all privileges on phpmyadmin table.
- manually edit /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf so as it reflects your current mysql server setup

```
dbc_dbserver = 'your_server'
dbc_dbport = 'your_mysql_port'
and any dbc_ fields that you feel need completion at this time
```

- manually edit `/etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php` so as it reflects your current mysql server setup

```
$dbserver = same_as_above
$dbport = your_mysql_listening_port
etc. - any other fields that you feel needs completing.
```

- run `dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` from console with root or administrative privileges
- choose Reinstall database for phpmyadmin - YES !!
- when configuration window asks what you want to do with existing configuration file, choose - "Keep the local version currently installed".
- In the console output you shouldn't have any mysql empty port errors anymore.

That worked for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imo. It just needs some extra clarification.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above helped in my case - because, somehow, `mysql` was not running / was not installed (check by `sudo systemctl status mysql`).

1. Skip the error in Phpmyadmin installation.
2. Reinstall mysql by `sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client`.
3. Reconfigure with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` and accept the defaults - they will be a bit different this time (but you may want to set the passwords).
4. Say yes to overwrite the config file with maintainer's version.

By the way, the port in phpmyadmin.conf remained `dbc_dbport=''`.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround, I was updating Ubuntu 14.04 -> 16.04:

- In the wizard select "tcp/ip" as connection method, localhost port 0
- Read the phpmyadmin user password from /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php
- Change the phpmyadmin user password in the db to it
- Paste it into the wizard (twice)

Wizard will run through :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this after I added passwords to both 'mysql' root and 'mysql' user. If you leave one or both of the two empty, you can do:

`sudo -i`

check:

`whoami`

if 'root', type:

`mysql`, or `mysql -u root -p` in case you already had a password for the root.

mysql terminal opens; then I added the passwords:

> mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH my_sql_native_password BY 'newpassword';

And/or the same for 'user' if needed. Then once I made the passwords for my user in MySQL and phpMyAdmin identical, I was done.

Before adding the passwords I applied @William Ardilla's as well as @user5781956's advice. Perhaps only @William Ardilla's is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the

---

My machine configuration - Ubuntu 16.04 - MySql 5.7.13 - PHP 7.0.8 - Apache 2.4.18

Edit the file `/etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf`, changing

```
dbc_dbport='' to dbc_dbport='0'
```

After editing the file and saving it, if you are still on the dbconfig-common wizard select retry; if not run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` (choose Yes when asked you if you want to Reinstall database for phpmyadmin) and continue normally without changing any value. If you want to change some value do it in the file that you have edited before.

When configuration window asks what you want to do with existing configuration file choose Keep the local version currently installed.

At this point you can check the differences and only those must exist that you made in the file.

---

Solution I also had to change this line:

```
"&& ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*')))" to "&& ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*'))"
```

After that everything worked!