# There was something wrong with my password. I got an error when installing phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-16.04

The error is shown as a screenshot by clicking the link:
[The error box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDlLe.png)

What can I do?

The error in text is:

> An error occurred while installing the database:
>     mysql said: mysql: [Warning] mysql: Empty value for 'port' specified. Will throw an error in future versions ERROR 1819 (HY000) at line 1: Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements . Your options are: 
>   * abort - Causes the operation to fail; you will need to downgrade,                                                                                                                                                           reinstall, reconfigure this package, or otherwise manually intervene                                                                                                                                                        to continue using it. This will usually also impact your ability to                                                                                                                                                         install other packages until the installation failure is resolved.                                                                                                                                                          * retry - Prompts once more with all the configuration questions                                                                                                                                                              (including ones you may have missed due to the debconf priority                                                                                                                                                             setting) and makes another attempt at performing the operation.                                                                                                                                                             * retry (skip questions) - Immediately attempts the operation again,                                                                                                                                                          skipping all questions. This is normally useful only if you have                                                                                                                                                            solved the underlying problem since the time the error occurred.                                                                                                                                                            * ignore - Continues the operation ignoring dbconfig-common errors.                                                                                                                                                           This will usually leave this package without a functional database.                                                                                                                                                         Next step for database installation:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089568/phpmyadmin-error-during-installation-empty-value-for-port-specified

Comment: I don't think that answers my question, because my error seems to have something to do with the password I set.

Answer (score 2):

Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements - probably it's too weak.
try this:
sudo apt-get remove --purge phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext && sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext

then: when prompted again for a password choose one with special char, upper and lower char, and numbers..

hope it helps